# Youcompleteme on Mac OS X

Tags: macvim, plugin-you-complete-me, macos

I'm trying to use the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) auto completion plugin.

I have installed MacVim version 7.4.

I followed the instructions on the linked page for Mac OS X  by making the symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/mvim vim
```

When installing the plugin with Vundle, I got some errors, which I unfortunately didn't copy or save. YCM however seems to be instaled.

When I open vim from the Terminal however, I get this, and there is no auto completion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/setup.py", line 37, in SetUpSystemPaths
    from ycmd import server_utils as su
  File "/Users/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/../../third_party/ycmd/ycmd/server_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import io
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YouCompleteMe does not work with Anaconda Python.](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1241)

Disable Anaconda by commenting out the relevant line from your `~/.bash_profile` and then try to install YouCompleteMe again. After that you can reenable Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to get it set up and fixed it with this line in my .zshrc

```
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
```

might give that a shot and see if it resolves.

Comment: Hi Slerm. I think I have succesfully installed YCM now on another computer (running Ubuntu). I say "I think" because the plugin shows in my list of plugins, and there are no errors when I start vim. How do I actually 'activate' YCM? Should it automatically start to autocomplete? Because it does not seem like that is the case.

Comment: Yeah it should automatically start. Try running `:YcmDebugInfo` in vim and see if it's yelling about anything.

Comment: Seems like I got it working on my PC running ubuntu, now I just have to get it running on my Mac. I tried your solution of putting `export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1` in my .bashrc file (I use bash, not zshell), but that didn't work. On my Ubuntu PC I had to build the Python support separately, I will try that on my Mac. On my Ubuntu machine, it seems that general code is being completed, but not Python built-in functions. Do you know if I need a specific configuration file for Python?

Comment: I have `let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1` set in my .vimrc and that seems to help with the built-ins.